# How can I use the Android virtual keyboard for my own custom ui object?

Tags: android, user-interface, keyboard

I am writing my own non-native ui system, so I will have my own non-ui related edittext widget but I want it to use the Android native virtual keyboard.

I am having quite a bit of trouble finding if/how this is done, can anyone help?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: LiamKjaer , I am facing same problem , have you got any solution ?